# Multichannel channel creation in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 , Can anyone please guide me in implementing multi-channel creation using Node SDK. I was referring Balance-transfer  example to do this [https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer] , But I am not able to do it .

Currently it's using only single channel and I am trying to do this in multi-channel,I have created 2 tx files mychannel.tx & mychannel2.tx and when I am creating the channel using mychannel2.tx the channel is created successfully. But not able to join the peer to mychannel2. I am getting error saying

> error code 500 : Cannot create ledger from genesis block, due to
>   LedgerID already exists

Because Earlier I have created my first channel using mychannel.tx and joined all the peer to this channel and again created second  channel and getting error while joining the same peer to another mychannel2. I found a file in balance-transfer app folder called config.json where they hard-coded `ChannelName = "mychannel"` and this config is used in Helper.js in app folder. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance,

Gins

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article (https://qiita.com/shiki_tak/items/a28a4cefe4e1d93e997a) to create multi channel, once you have the config and network up, you can work on balance transfer app.

Note: Article is in Japanese, use translator :)

Comment: this article is for multi-channel creation through cli and I have already achieved this but what I want is to achieve this multi-channel creation in hyperledger fabric using NODE SDK. !!

Comment: @Gins Did you find a way to create multiple channels in hyperledger fabric using fabric-node-sdk. If yes then please let us know the solution